# How to get the SVN URL for a file in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

In eclipse you can right click on a file to get its properties. These include the SVN URL of the file. I can't see how to get the SVN URL easily in netbeans. I'm using 6.8.

Answer (score 1):

This was a lazy question.
Maybe this feature has been added to netbeans 6.9.
The answer is: right click on file, then Subversion, then Versioning Info,